# How to make go to "link" button from option value?

Tags: javascript, html, button

How to make go to "link" button after changing option value and click sumbit?
I've got problem, because when I change value it's going to "link" before i click submit

```
<form action="search-form" method="post">
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value" >
<option value="here comes a link nr 1">coffie medium</option>
<option value="here comes a link nr 2">coffe big</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><img src="xyz.JPG"    width="240" height="72"> 
</button>
</form>
```

Comment: remove onChange="window.location.href=this.value" from your select tag

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `onchange` from the `select` element and write a listener for your submit button (you are using `search-form` action already)

```
<form action="search-form" method="post">
<select>
<option value="here comes a link nr 1">coffie medium</option>
<option value="here comes a link nr 2">coffe big</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><img src="xyz.JPG"    width="240" height="72"> 
</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT**:
@Peril Adding a solution as requested. Now it is working if you use `onsubmit` for the form submit as per below. Note that you should give valid links for the `option` values

```js
function submit_form() {
    window.location.href= document.getElementById('select-box').value;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="submit_form()" method="post">
        <select id="select-box">
        <option value="http://google.com">coffie medium</option>
        <option value="http://yahoo.com">coffe big</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
```

**EDIT 2**:
@Peril Normally we load external links into a page when we click on `anchor` tag. If you load it using `window.location.href`, you will get the `cross-origin access` error. Take the below snippet into a local html file and check it out.

```js
// load href initially
document.getElementById('form-button').setAttribute('action', document.getElementById('select-box').value);
// load href on value change of select
function onChangeValue() {
  document.getElementById('form-button').setAttribute('action', document.getElementById('select-box').value);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <select id="select-box" onchange="onChangeValue()">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">coffie medium</option>
    <option value="http://www.facebook.com">coffe big</option>
  </select>
  <form action="#" id="form-button" style="display:inline">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: @Peril have used the `onsubmit` javascript listener to load the page from the option values. Hope it answers your queries :) Upvote / mark as accepted if this helped you. Thanks!

Comment: I've got problem with this still, I have firefox and button isn't redirecting me to e.g. google

Comment: maybe because of iframe restrictions here... copy into an html file and open that html file in the browser and check?

Comment: yeah I worked on Dreamweaver and I tried on the browser and it doesn't want work

Comment: ohh, cross origin restrictions, sorry I forgot about that. will get back to you with an answer tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Try including in your select the attribute 'onchange' and in the value of option the link, how that:

```
<select name="form" onchange="location = this.value;">
<option value="Home.php">Home</option>
<option value="Contact.php">Contact</option>
<option value="Sitemap.php">Sitemap</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the onchange event from select box and validate it in js on button click. If the page redirects what is the use of submit button

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="search-form" method="post">
<select>
<option value="here comes a link nr 1">coffie medium</option>
<option value="here comes a link nr 2">coffe big</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><img src="xyz.JPG"    width="240" height="72"> 
</button>
</form>
```

This isn't working, it only ads to adres url "search-form"

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if you use JavaScript or Jquery?

First Created the select:

```
<select name="form" id="form">
<option value="url">Home</option>
<option value="url">Contact</option>
<option value="url">Sitemap</option>
</select>
```

Try .change for assing a new location:

```
$("#form").change(function(){
var url = $(this).val();
location.assign(url);
});
```